# Rails Tutorial 3 Chapter 9.1: Rspec tests failing when should be passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm a rails noob and have been working through Michael Hartl's awesome Rails 3 tutorial with great success.  So far all my tests have worked when they should have (per the book).  However, I'm at the [beginning of chapter 9](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#top) and am failing rspec tests that should be passing - i.e. functionality in the browser is perfect.

I've checked everything and even looked at the sample app's github repo but still can't figure out how to cure my rspec woes.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

### The Errors in Question

```
    1) Authentication signin with valid information 
       Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('a', 'Sign out', href: signout_path) }
         expected css "Sign out" to return something
       # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

    2) Authentication signin with valid information 
       Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
         expected css "title" with text "Example User" to return something
       # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

    3) User pages signup edit page 
       Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit User" ) }
         expected css "title" with text "Edit User" to return something
       # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:72:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

### Other App Files

**spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end 

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_selector('a', 'Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
  let (:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } #Using factory girl to create the test user

  before { visit user_path(user) }

  it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }

        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }


        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end
    end

    describe "edit" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

      describe "page" do 
        it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit User" ) }
        it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
      end

      describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Save changes" }

        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
      end
  end
end
```

**app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
   <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
         <div class="container">
          <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
              <% if signed_in? %>
                <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
                <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Account <b class="caret"></b>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                      <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

**app/views/users/edit.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %> 
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your Capybara version?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti - I'm using 1.1.2

Comment: That version is almost 18 months old.  Upgrading to a more recent version would be helpful, especially since a lot of the current documentation is going to be wrong for that version.

Comment: Can you share your github repo?

Answer (score 0):

### Solved Update!

Thanks for the comments guys.  I ended up getting the tests to pass by doing a combination of a couple things:

- Restarted Rails
- Continued following the book until the end of 9.2.1

After doing both of these things the test suite turned green as expected. Hopefully this can help out someone stuck in the same situation.